# Are there situations where if statements are irreplaceable by jump tables?

Tags: java, c, logic

I did not went too deep into this idea, but i wonder if if statements can be replaced by jump tables.

If we have a set of ifs like

```
if(x = 0)
{
...
}
if(x = 1)
{
...
} 
if(x = 2)
{
...
}
```

We could simply jump, direcly, to the routine that pertains to the value of x, if we had a table with pointers for each routine.

In other situations like user input, let's assume we read a character from stdin, we 
 would have like

```
if(c = 'a')
{
...
}
if(c = 'b')
{
...
}
```

We could also find a way to índex a jump table based on the value of c

My question is, in which situations is it TOTALLY impossible to replace an if by a jump table? Can computation be performed without if statements (or equivalents)

Comment: "irreplaceable"? Trivially, yes. Consider `if (f > PI)` of even `if (l > LONG_MAX - 1)`, neither of which can be represented (practically) by a fixed-lookup table. Jump tables only work well over a *relatively small finite fixed set*.

Comment: use `==` instead of `=` in C.

Answer (score 0):

Jump tables are limited to situations when you check equality. They are less appropriate when you need to use non-equality checks, and also for `if` statements with `OR` conditions.

Of course you could always use a degenerate jump table on a single boolean condition, like this:

```
boolean condition = a > b && c < d || e != f;
switch (condition) {
case true: ... break;
case false: ... break;
}
```

However, this does not offer any advantage over a straightforward conditional.